# Optional dependencies in copy-dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

Using the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/), is there a way I can copy `<optional>true</optional>` dependencies when using the copy-dependencies goal? I can't find any reference to it but I also can't find any reference to it NOT doing it either. It seems that even the `tree` goal ignores optional dependencies

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue about it: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-266 However, no fix version is on it.

Comment: i saw that one; however, this confused me: "I just added an optional dependency to copy-dependencies IT in r1481566, and it is copied"